# My Cake won't bake

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line-interface

Hi I'm trying to run the bake cmd on my ubuntu server but it's not processing as I'd expected it to.

I run the following

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/cake bake all
```

and I expect it to create models, controllers and views for the related table but instead I am getting

enter code here

```
# Canonicalize by following every symlink of the given name recursively
canonicalize() {
    NAME="$1"
    if [ -f "$NAME" ]
    then
        DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
        NAME=$(cd -P "$DIR" > /dev/null && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$NAME")
    fi
    while [ -h "$NAME" ]; do
        DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
        SYM=$(readlink "$NAME")
        NAME=$(cd "$DIR" > /dev/null && cd $(dirname -- "$SYM") > /dev/null && p                 wd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
    done
    echo "$NAME"
}

# Find a CLI version of PHP
findCliPhp() {
    for TESTEXEC in php php-cli /usr/local/bin/php
    do
        SAPI=`echo "cli" | $TESTEXEC 2>/dev/null`
        if [ "$SAPI" = "cli" ]
        then
            echo $TESTEXEC
            return
        fi
    done
    echo "Failed to find a CLI version of PHP; falling back to system standard p                 hp executable" >&2
    echo "php";
}

CONSOLE=$(dirname -- "$(canonicalize "$0")")
APP=$(dirname "$CONSOLE")

# If your CLI PHP is somewhere that this doesn't find, you can define a PHP envi                 ronment
# variable with the correct path in it.
if [ -z "$PHP" ]
then
    PHP=$(findCliPhp)
fi

if [ $(basename $0) != 'cake' ]
then
    exec $PHP "$CONSOLE"/cake.php $(basename $0) "$@"
else
    exec $PHP "$CONSOLE"/cake.php "$@"
fi

exit
```

I have tried every version of php on my server 7.0 to 7.2.9

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put php in front of cake executable file in bin directory, but if you want that you can simply call `cake.php` file.

Change that line to:

```sh
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/cake.php bake all
```

**Or**

Also, as suggested in the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/usage.html

Only use:

```sh
bin/cake bake all
```

Hope this helps.